# GCP AI-Platform cannot see files in project buckets

Tags: machine-learning, deployment, google-ai-platform, gcp-ai-platform-training

I successfully trained my model in GCP AI-Platform, saving my model in a pkl file in my project bucket path:

```
gs://mybucket-mymodel/trained_model/topic_20210820_191116/mymodel.pkl
```

The distribution file of my model is in the bucket path:

```
gs://mybucket-mymodel/mysourcecode-0.1.2.tar.gz
```

Now I am trying to deploy and create the version of the model from gcloud console, but apparently the pkl and the distribution files cannot be seen when I run the gcloud command below.

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create "v0_1_2" \
  --model="mymodel" \
  --origin=gs://mybucket-mymodel/trained_model/topic_20210820_191116/ \
  --runtime-version=2.1 \
  --framework="scikit-learn" \
  --python-version=3.7 \
  --machine-type="mls1-c1-m2" \
  --region="europe-west4"
  --package-uris=gs://mybucket-mymodel/mysourcecode-0.1.2.tar.gz \
  --enable-console-logging
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai-platform.versions.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: Field: 
version.deployment_uri Error: Deployment directory gs://mybucket- 
mymodel/trained_model/topic_20210820_191116/ is expected to contain exactly one of: 
[model.pkl, model.joblib].
 - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
 fieldViolations:
    - description: 'Deployment directory gs://dft-amis-dspct-prt-topic- 
       model/trained_model/topic_20210820_191116/
        is expected to contain exactly one of: [model.pkl, model.joblib].'
      field: version.deployment_uri
 ./versions.sh: line 10: --package-uris=gs://mybucket-mymodel/mysourcecode- 
    0.1.2.tar.gz: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you try running `gsutil ls gs://mybucket-mymodel/` and `gsutil ls gs://mybucket-mymodel/trained_model/topic_20210820_191116/` just to double check if the files really exist?

Comment: Hi @RiccoD thanks a lot for your message. I fixed it. I had to call the file exactly model.pkl and not mymodel or an other name. Also after --region flag I missed the slash symbol \ 

They were just some details, these are fixed! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As confirmed by @Annalix, the fix was provide the model file called exactly as 'model'  and not 'mymodel' (model.pkl and not mymodel.pkl) and escape (\) the end of line on --region flag.

```
gcloud beta ai-platform versions create "v0_1_2" \
  --model="mymodel.pkl" \
  --origin=gs://mybucket-mymodel/trained_model/topic_20210820_191116/ \
  --runtime-version=2.1 \
  --framework="scikit-learn" \
  --python-version=3.7 \
  --machine-type="mls1-c1-m2" \
  --region="europe-west4" \
  --package-uris=gs://mybucket-mymodel/mysourcecode-0.1.2.tar.gz \
  --enable-console-logging
```